# Insert column at beginning of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, arff

How can I add a column to an R `data.frame` as a new first column so that all other columns are shifted by one column?

Like:

```
a|b|c --> new|a|b|c
```

I need to do this because I want the `row.names` to become a discrete column. This is needed because the `write.arff` function takes a `data.frame` as input but does not preserve the names when writing files.

Comment: `cbind(rownames(df), df)`?

Comment: Thank you. I now realize that I asked something really basic but somehow I did not find the answer.

Comment: on a side note, are you exporting for using in `Weka`?  There is very little that can be done in Weka that cannot already be done in R without the need for the intermittent step

Comment: @RicardoSaporta Yes it is for using in `WEKA`. As you might see from my question I am not so familiar with R but have been using `WEKA` for quite a while. So nevertheless I will probably stay with it. But I will have a look on the machine learning functions in R.

Answer (score 7):

This has been answered in the comments, but to make it clearer that there is an answer, here's a small example:

First, some sample data:

```
(df <- data.frame(A = 1:2, B = 3:4, row.names = c("row1", "row2")))
#      A B
# row1 1 3
# row2 2 4
```

The suggestion from the comments. Note that the original `row.names` is still part of the data.

```
cbind(rn = rownames(df), df)
#        rn A B
# row1 row1 1 3
# row2 row2 2 4
```

You can get rid of that by setting `row.names = NULL` in the `cbind` step. Since you are `cbind`ing `data.frames`, you could also pass other arguments to `data.frame` if necessary (such as `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` if you didn't want the "rn" column to be a `factor`).

```
cbind(rn = rownames(df), df, row.names = NULL)
#     rn A B
# 1 row1 1 3
# 2 row2 2 4
```